# Tmux command to open configuration

Tags: tmux

I would like to have a binding in tmux to make a vertical split and open `~/.tmux.conf` with vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bind-key C-k split-window vim ~/.tmux.conf
```

This will bind <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> so that when you press <kbd>Prefix</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> by default) followed by <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> it will split the current pane and open the configuration file for editing in `vim`.

Comment: it says unknown command split-pane when reloading the config.

Comment: @Arturo Hmmm try `split-window`.